# Edit object size after placed in ArCore world

Tags: flutter, arcore

I'm trying to edit an AR cube inside the ArCore environment after it's already been placed all this in a flutter environment (school project).

According to the following debug menu the object has a structure like this: [image: Object structure]

Which is also visable in the code when making the object:

```
import 'package:vector_math/vector_math_64.dart' as vector; /// Adding the import here because it's named one

final material = ArCoreMaterial(
  color: Colors.accents[Random().nextInt(14)],
  metallic: 0,
  roughness: 1,
);

final cube = ArCoreCube(
  materials: [material],
  size: vector.Vector3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5),
);

final node = ArCoreNode(
    shape: cube,
    position: plane.pose.translation + vector.Vector3(0, 0.25, 0),
    rotation: plane.pose.rotation
);

arCoreController.addArCoreNodeWithAnchor(node);
```

The **[plugin](https://github.com/giandifra/arcore_flutter_plugin)** to be able to use ArCore in flutter itself has an **[example](https://github.com/giandifra/arcore_flutter_plugin/blob/master/example/lib/screens/runtime_materials.dart#L118)** on how to edit the material during runtime:

```
final material = ArCoreMaterial(
  color: color,
  metallic: metallic,
  roughness: roughness,
  reflectance: reflectance,
);

sphereNode.shape.materials.value = [material];
```

As you can see from the above structure it's the same from the picture.

However when trying to edit the size which is a vector3 I'm unable to edit it.

```
object.shape.size.value  = vector.Vector3(25, 25, 25);     /// Class 'Vector3' has no instance setter 'value='.
object.shape.size.value  = [ vector.Vector3(25, 25, 25) ]; /// Class 'Vector3' has no instance setter 'value='.
object.shape.size        = vector.Vector3(25, 25, 25);     /// Class 'ArCoreCube' has no instance setter 'size='.
object.shape.size._value = vector.Vector3(25, 25, 25);     /// Class 'Vector3' has no instance setter '_value'.
```

These all fail.

I have also tried to use scale:

```
object.scale.value  = vector.Vector3(0.25, 0.25, 0.25); /// No error, no visual change
object.scale.value  = vector.Vector3(25, 25, 25);       /// No error, no visual change
object.scale.value  = [ vector.Vector3(25, 25, 25) ];   /// type 'List<Vector3>' is not a subtype of type 'Vector3' of 'newValue'
```

While I do not get an error with the correct scale property they don't change while the material on the object does.